# Creating an HTML-style label item in the layout that links to an anchor in the page

Tags: qgis-3, table, pdf, layouts, html

Initial research tells me this might not be possible, but let's try it anyway. In a Layout, I'd like to have an HTML-rendered label near the top of page 1 like:

```
<a href="#table">Jump to table</a>
```

If I create this, QGIS renders it as a link just fine.

But I'd like it to jump to a label on the second page, like:

```
<a name="table">Lorem ipsum this is intro text for the table etc.</a>
```

When I export to PDF, that link doesn't function as I'd expect. Searching for an existing feature request and will log a new one if I can't find an existing one. In the meantime, maybe somebody has done this and can spot my error.

Comment: I tried "id" instead of "name" in the anchor, too...doesn't seem to make a difference.